# troubles caused by tensorflow image's LD_LIBRARY_PATH

Tags: gpu, dcos

I'v installed DC/OS v1.8.4, the destination node has gpu resources and nvidia driver has also been installed, I tried to deploy tensorflow in mesos container, but it  failed, there is only one error message in mesos's stderr:

```
mesos-containerizer: error while loading shared libraries: libmesos-1.0.1.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

But I can deploy other services successfuly, such as nginx, wordpress (also in mesos container)

The problem may be caused by tensorflow image, in its parent image CUDA, it reset LD_LIBRARY_PATH :

```
ENV PATH /usr/local/nvidia/bin:/usr/local/cuda/bin:${PATH} ENV LD_LIBRARY_PATH /usr/local/nvidia/lib:/usr/local/nvidia/lib64
```

In OpenDCOS, before mesos-agent startup, it sets its executor's environment variable LD_LIBRARY_PATH to "/opt/mesosphere/lib", so that executor can locate necessary so files, but in above case, LD_LIBRARY_PATH is reset by tensorflow, so it failed to startup!

Anyone knows how OpenDCOS handle this problem ?   Modify these public CUDA images?

Answer (score 0):

GPUs are only officially supported in DC/OS 1.9+

For (unsupported) instructions on getting GPUs to work in 1.8, please see my answer to this question on the DC/OS mailing list:
https://groups.google.com/a/dcos.io/d/msg/users/HEgcUfRRqzk/inIBmapMCQAJ

Additionally, there is also a know issue with setting LD_LIBRARY_PATH in your container image for pre 1.9 clusters (though it usually manifests as a missing libssl.so library).

In your case, the CUDA container is setting LD_LIBRARY_PATH, which is overriding the LD_LIBRARY_PATH setting that DC/OS relies on to find it's library files. This is obviously a bug in DC/OS and has since been fixed in 1.9. The best (unsupported) workaround for this is to run

```
sudo ldconfig /opt/mesosphere/lib
```

on all of your nodes to put `/opt/mesosphere/lib` into the default library path. You will have to redo this on every reboot (or alternatively) add `/opt/mesosphere/lib` to a file under `/etc/ld.so.conf.d/` to make it durable (maybe `/etc/ld.so.conf.d/dcos.conf`?).

This JIRA addressing the underlying issue can be found here:
https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MESOS-7027